# Running perfmon /report yields Access Denied. Error when run as admin

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, performance-monitor

I opened an Administrator command prompt window today to run the Resources and Performance Monitor via the `perfmon /report` command and after a few seconds of scanning performance, it presents me with the following error:

> An error occurred while attempting to generate the report.
>   Access Denied.

I even tried turning off Webroot (my malware and virus scanner) to run the command, but I end up with the same result.

Comment: C:\perflogs\System\Diagnostics\ in there are there all the xml file things (mabey specific one it didnt make ~39) ?  Is the name of the computer so weird that it made a bad folder? Are some services turned off? Is it possible that it could have been effected by a temp system enviroment variable?  because other programs messing with env variables and making a mess , and perf stuff often uses temps .  (today would be the first time i had used it, so i am just trying to think of possibles.)

Comment: I've only got C:\Perflogs\Admin\ and that folder is empty.  The computer's name is leeand00-laptop, that doesn't seem like it would cause an issue...I'm able to create that folder.

Comment: I did at one point go through and make some changes to the services to eeek a bit more performance out of the system...so that one has potential.  I think I'll go find out what services are dependent on perfmon...

Comment: My ENV Variables should be okay...I do all of my development in VMs.

Comment: **no folder for the xmls** <-- this and--> **after a few seconds of scanning** might indicate it didnt get very far? like even the first report?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: resource monitor working? then what service would be involved in xml , and then dcom or some internal cross communications stuff (that overly complicates everything:-) event viewer parts and pieces, and device manager, disk manager, net manager, you could check of those are working independantly